# Alternative keyboard-triggred launcher for specific file type in file managers (Dolphin and/or nautilus)

Tags: linux, gnome, kde, nautilus, dolphin

Is it possible to have an (or some) alternative launchers (i.e. Open With) for each file type and  be able to trigger them using keyboard modifier keys (Shift, Ctrl & Alt) in linux's `KDE` and/or `Gnome` file managers (`Dolphin` and/or `Nautilus`)?

For example I want to use both `mplayer` & `VLC` for playing video files but I want VLC be the main and mplayer be the alternative (#1); so when I double click or hit enter on a video file it will open with `VLC` but when I do the same holding Shift/Ctrl/Alt it open with `mplayer`...

Is there such a feature?

Thanks